# How to Un-flatten a smart contract in Soliditty?

Tags: solidity

There are many ways/tools to flatten a contract but is there anything that unflattens it and creates a folder structure with all the imports?

**Example:** contract codes that are available on the Etherscan or BSCscan - https://bscscan.com/address/0x10bc28d2810dd462e16facff18f78783e859351b#code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created a tool for that, actually. I had that same issue and thought the same as you. There were no tools to undo that flattening process.

Just use this command:

```bash
npx @devdavi/unflatten FlattenedContract.sol [output_dir]
```

And you will have the separated contracts again.

- A blog post showing how it works:
  https://blog.devdavi.io/how-to-unflatten-solidity-contracts#heading-solidity-unflattener
- NPM page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@devdavi/unflatten
- Repository: https://github.com/developerdavi/solidity-unflattener